# Expectation of $Y$ when $X,Y$ are jointly distributed.

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $X,Y$ are jointly distributed continuous random variables with probability density function $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$. I know that in order to recover the marginal distribution of one of the random variables, say $Y$, we can compute $$f_{Y}(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx .$$

My question is about computing $E[Y]$ when starting from the above situation. Considering the fact that the definition of the expectation is $$E[Y] := \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \cdot f_{Y}(y) \, dy, $$

My approach is then to compute the expectation as $$E[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \cdot f_Y(y) \, dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \left[ \int_{\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx \,\right] dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dx \, dy. $$

However, I regularly see solutions that will compute it as $$E[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy \, dx. $$

I am familiar with the concept of changing the order of integration, but this seems like more than that. It is no longer clear to me why this still fits the definition of the expected value, because I don't see how we are recovering the marginal pdf of $Y$ and then integrating it against $y$ to arrive at the expectation. I have asked several friends who also solved problems this way why it is valid and none of them seem to have an answer and they just say "why wouldn't you be able to calculate it this way?". So either I am crazy or they are unconscious statisticians.

---

On that note, I did notice on a formula page in a text book it has an identity:

$$E[g(X,Y)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,y) \cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dy \, dx.$$

In the above I agree the order of integration wont matter (by setting X = Y and vice versa). I suppose in this result if you take the function $g(X,Y) = Y$ it will permit the computation that I am hesitant about. Is this how we know we can do that? Or is it simpler than that and I am just being crazy?

---

As a concrete example, here is a specific problem where the solution provided uses the method I am hesitant about.

*Let $X$ and $Y$ denote the values of two stocks at the end of a five-year period. $X$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,12)$. Given $X = x$, $Y$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,x)$. Find $E[Y]$.*

**Please remember, my question is not how to solve this problem. It is why a specific method works.**

**My method** of solving this would be to first discover that the support of $(X,Y)$ is $0 < y < x < 12$. Then since $f_{Y|X}(y|x) = x^{-1}$ and $f_{X}(x) = 12^{-1}$ we can deduce that $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = (12x)^{-1}$. Then compute

$$f_{Y}(y) = \int_{y}^{12} (12x)^{-1} \, dx = (1/12)[\ln(12) - \ln(y)].$$

Then use this to compute

$$E[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} y \cdot f_{Y}(y) \, dy = \int_{0}^{12} y \cdot (1/12)[\ln(12) - \ln(y)] \, dy = 3.$$

Computing the last integral was... 'do-able' for a well-practiced integrater, but it was not ideal.

**The solution posted** was the following:

$$E[Y] = \int_{0}^{12} \int_{0}^{x} (y/12x) \, dy \, dx = 3.$$

The above integral is much easier to solve, so once I understand this is a valid way to compute the expectation I will happily add this to my tool belt for solving problems. But again, I don't see how it fits the definition of expectation, because I don't see how it is recovering the marginal distribution for $Y$. Unless, doing it this way is using the identity that I mention in the middle block of text.

> So why is the other method valid?

Comment: "I am familiar with the concept of changing the order of integration, but this seems like more than that."  It is exactly that.

Comment: You know what, it entirely is. If you start with my definition you can just work a chain of equalities down to the other one. I think I was just confused seeing it presented not derived from the other one because I didn't see how it represented $y \cdot f_{Y}(y)$, but if the resulting integral is equivalent then it will be equal to $E[Y]$

Comment: So, in $\textbf{general}$ if $R$ is the support of my joint pdf I can compute $E[Y]$ as $ \int \int_{R} y \cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y) \, dA$?

Comment: As long as the preconditions of Fubini are satisfied, than yes.

Comment: As far as I am concerned the definition of $E[Y]$ is being given to me as an iterated integral, so then what is the product integral that I would want to determine absolute convergence over?

Comment: And to be honest I didn't go very far in analysis, pretty much as long as I am over a bounded region and my function has no blow ups over my region, Fubini should hold, right? .... But wait, isn't the integrand in my example question blowing up near the origin? How do they know Fubinis works here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $\mathbb E[|Y|]<\infty$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f_{X,Y}(x,y)|\ \mathsf dx<\infty$, by Fubini's theorem the integral
$$
\iint_{\mathbb R^2} yf_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathsf dm(x\times y)
$$
exists, and is equal to the integrated integrals
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty y f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy
$$
and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty y f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathsf dy\ \mathsf dx.
$$

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb{E}[|Y|] > \infty$, or $\mathbb{E}[|Y|] < \infty$?

Comment: @PrinceM Definitely $<\infty$, 'twas a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: No problem. Also, something else I think I don't understand about Fubini's is - the theorem is telling us when the double integral $\int \int _{X \times Y}  f(x,y) d(x,y)$ is equal to the iterated integrals with opposite order, but what definition are we using for that double integral? Is that a Lesbegue integral? Is this theorem in the context of measure theory? All of my upper level courses and graduate work were in abstract algebra, so the subtle differences between a 'double integral' and 'iterated integral' are hard for me to grasp.

Comment: The calculus that I remember most is just general undergrad single and multivariable calc where we are using the Riemman integral and double integrals are essentially defined as iterated integrals.

Answer (score 1):

It's a general fact that
 $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x,y)\ dx\ dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x,y)\ dy\ dx,$$
provided that the integral exists. In particular this applies to $g(x,y)=yf_{X,Y}(x,y)$, as in your question.

Now you may ask why it is true, in which case I can either quote a theorem from a more advanced subject (this is what the other answer does) or I can explain why it has to be true, intuitively.

Think of the integrand $g(x,y)$ as a height function. In other words, we can think of a hill whose height above the point $(x,y)$ is $g(x,y)$. Then there are two ways of finding the volume of the hill: first you can subdivide into thin strips in the $x$ direction, and add up the volumes along each of those thin strips - or you can subdivide in the $y$ direction. Either way, you will get the same answer in the end, since the volume of the hill does not care which way we chop up the hill to calculate it. That's why the two integrals are the same.

Comment: Both answers are good. I do like rigorous approaches because I am very pedantic, but I appreciate you trying to give a more intuitive approach. In general, I see orders of integration being reversed all the time with out mention of checking the conditions of Fubini that the original integral is absolutely convergent? In most cases it makes sense to ignore if the integrand-function is bounded and the region of integration is bounded, but in the example I provided the function is blowing up near the origin, right? Should more precaution be made or is it still plain to see the integral exists?

Comment: The Riemann integral of a non-negative continuous function always exists but may be equal to $+\infty$. The Lebesgue integral of a non-negative measurable function always exists but may be equal to $+\infty$. (This is more precisely known as the Tonelli theorem.) Integral of a function which can take positive and negative values is ill-defined without more conditions, since the positive part and the negative part can each integrate to $+\infty$, and then you have to subtract two infinities. Regarding your edit with the blow up at zero, more should be said.